# Trouble running Common Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm a bit of a beginner at programming and wanted to try some basic Common Lisp. However this is turning out to be a real hassle when you get down to it. I'm currently using a Mac and need to find some good software for running Common Lisp. Does anyone know a simple download for running Common Lisp code? The current one I'm using does not allow you to edit code via text editor and run it. Thanks!

Comment: If you're using [Homebrew](http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/) (I highly recommend it), all you need is `brew install clisp`.

Answer (score 6):

The ubiquitous [CLISP](http://www.clisp.org/) provides a straightforward, plain-jane file-based environment on any platform.

Answer (score 4):

Try Clozure Common Lisp: http://ccl.clozure.com/

It even has an bundled IDE

Answer (score 4):

Clozure Common Lisp can be installed via Apple's Mac App Store.

http://itunes.apple.com/de/app/clozure-cl/id489900618?mt=12

Answer (score 3):

[Lispbox](http://common-lisp.net/project/lispbox/) is a pre-configured lisp environment. They support the big three OSes.

If you're more into IDEs than Emacs, [Lispworks Personal](http://www.lispworks.com/downloads/index.html) is a crippleware environment that should be fine for some basic playing around.